# How to update the URL with Turbolinks and rails 4

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, url, browser-history

I'm on Rails 4. I am trying to update the URL when an AJAX is called so that I can use the back button and refresh the page with the right partial. I have been looking on the internet without success. What would be the process or even if there is a tutorial out there?